Why does IV smile imply a more "peaked" distribution than lognormal?
Below, Hull claims that a U-shaped volatility smile suggests that "both small and large movements in the [underlying] are more likely than with the lognormal distribution, and intermediate movements are less likely."
I see why the smile suggests that the implied distribution has fatter tails than the lognormal distribution, since the higher tail IV indicates that the market assigns a higher probability to extreme underlying price movements.
However, I don't see why the U-shaped smile suggests that the implied distribution also has a higher peak, with more probability assigned to small movements. By the previous logic, since the smile dips for $K/S_0\approx 1$, doesn't it mean that the market assigns a lower probability to small underlying price movements?


If you increase the probability of the tail events while reducing the probability of small moves, you will have increased the standard deviation of the distribution.  The passage in Hull assumes that you need to maintain the same standard deviation (because you want to calibrate to the same ATM volatility). This latter implies that the distribution must get very skinny in the middle to make up for the fatter tails.

Why do you want to calibrate to the same ATM volatility though?
